# Some options for making augmented local maps with d3

Tags: d3.js, maps

I am new to d3 geo. My task is to make a map of Boston and add some interactive features to it.

So far I've been able to get an outline of Boston. But the base map should be comparable to something you'd see in Google Maps - it should have buildings, roads, street names and city names, rivers, etc. A basic geography that makes the region more familiar.

For now, I don't need to pan, and may have just two or three zoom states.

All the visualizations I've seen that overlay interactive features onto maps like this seem to use images for the underlying maps: [windhistory](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fwindhistory.com%2Fmap.html%239.00%2F37.6450%2F-121.8561&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNHlrhUK72gm7sC7EHbHCIucYWH72g), [polymaps](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbl.ocks.org%2Fmbostock%2F899670&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNG9g_tY4wYfR2PiW5z5c1i8sTr2GA), [google maps](http://www.google.com/url?q=http%3A%2F%2Fbl.ocks.org%2Fmbostock%2F899711&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNEn5A8Fx0QAWQezUEBnLSh9Fptu8Q) and more. So I guess my questions are:

1. **Why do some maps use images for the "backdrop"?** Is it just the easiest way to build on top of existing maps? Is it more performant?
2. **If I go with the images approach, are there any limitations to the features I can add?** I'm hoping to do things like windmaps, animations, heatmaps, etc.
3. **What are the copyright implications for using images?** I imagine the answer to this is, "depends on which images I use," but are there some standard libraries that have no strings attached? For example I know if I use Google Maps, I have to display their logo, there's an API limit, etc. Are there any standard sources that are completely open?
4. **Are there any examples where geography is added purely through TopoJSON?**

Sorry if some of these seem obvious, but I am completely new to maps and just don't know the standard practices. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 2):

A quick take on your questions.  Hopefully someone with more mapping experience can give you more detail:

1. **Why do some maps use images for the "backdrop"?**

   File size and computation time, mostly.  Drawing complete maps with buildings, roads, and topography requires a lot of data and a lot of time for the browser to render it.  If your browser DOM gets too complicated, it can slow down all interactions even after the original drawing.
2. **If I go with the images approach, are there any limitations to the features I can add?**

   There's a reason most interactive maps use multiple layers.  The background images are best for the underlying "lay of the land" type imagery, anything you want to be interactive should be on top with SVG.
3. **What are the copyright implications for using images?**

   If you're using someone's images, you have to follow their licence.  You might want to look at the [OpenStreetMap project](http://www.openstreetmap.org/).
4. **Are there any examples where geography is added purely through TopoJSON?**

   I suppose that depends on what you mean by "geography"; Mike Bostock has generated topoJSON for a variety of features based on [US Atlas data](https://github.com/mbostock/us-atlas).

   As for whether it makes sense: TopoJSON encodes paths/boundaries directly, and encodes regions as the area enclosed by a set of boundaries.  You could use it to encode streets and rivers and even building outlines, but you're not saving any file size relative regular GeoJSON because those paths generally aren't duplicated the way that region boundaries are.  Relative to using image tiles, any improvement in file size would be countered with increased processing time.

Comment: Very helpful, thanks a lot! It makes sense, I just had no idea that's how it was done, and I thought all d3 maps were made with d3.geo only. Great resources, esp. OpenStreeMap. I'll check them out.

Comment: AmeliaBR I came across [this example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5616813) which seems to paint all the parts in SVG. Any insight there?

Comment: That's interesting -- it's still using image "tiles" for the background, but the tiles are SVG.  I guess the benefit is that the SVG properties are all pre-calculated instead of having to figure out the map projection and scale during runtime.  And also that you can still load each tile as needed depending on the position of the map -- you don't need to load up the entire dataset all at once.